# Como setar um parâmetro de uma função do postgres usando native query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

Boa tarde!

Eu criei uma native query que usa uma função do postgres *date_part(text, timestamp)*. Meu código:

```java
String sql = "SELECT "
                + "(SELECT coalesce(count(*), 0) FROM public.cliente) AS totalClientes, "
                + "(SELECT coalesce(count(*), 0) FROM cliente WHERE date_part('year', dt_cadastro) = date_part('year', :ano) ) AS totalNovosClientes";
                
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
        query.setParameter("ano", "2021-01-01");
```

O problema é que na hora de setar esse parâmetro ano dá um erro falando que eu tenho que explicitar os casts. Outras maneiras que eu tentei mas que também não funcionaram:

```java
date_part('year', TIMESTAMP :ano)
query.setParameter("ano", "2021-01-01");
query.setParameter("ano", java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("2021-01-01 10:10:10.0"), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP );
```

Como eu poderia setar o valor na função usando o query.setParameter de maneira correta?

Comment: se vai usar data, a query não deveria ser assim `date_part('year', ':ano')`,?

Comment: @RicardoPontual tentei assim tbm não funcionou

Comment: Poderia mostrar qual o erro que ele exibe?